# Find position of a SQL Syntax Error from System.Data.ODBC.ODBCException?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, exception, odbc

The Goal of my program is to allow our support technicians to run queries on a Faircom, c-tree Plus database while logged in as a user with limited rights.

I have the program running and, as long as their script is good, it's just fine.

But when they have the wrong table, column or, even worse, a syntax error; the information available in the System.Data.ODBC.ODBCException doesn't seem to give me the ability to tell the user what line/position in their script they need to focus their attention.

Line that throws the error:

```
OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Exception.Message:

```
ERROR [2a504] [FairCom][ODBC FairCom Driver 9.3.55632(Build-110208_120517)][ctreeSQL] -20003 Syntax error
```

Exception.Source:

```
CTODBC9.DLL
```

Exception.StackTrace:

```
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at QueryDentrixDatabase.Form1.RunQuery(String query) in C:\Users\caanderson\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\...\Form1.cs:line 193
```

I would really like to give more information than "Syntax Error"

Comment: What kind of database? Have you seen SQLServer parser: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx

Comment: It's a Faircom C-Tree Ace (v9.5) database.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error and as you mentioned it was hard to debug.  Here are couple of things I have done to make it work in my case, hopefully it is helpful for anyone else looking at this thread:

1. Ensure there is no ';' at the end of the SQL Statement.
2. Replace the named parameters with '?'.